# Method Range.Replace replacing all values, including the ones that end like the one being searched

Tags: excel, vba

The code below is supposed to replace 9.9000 for 9.900, but if the sheet contains 19.9000, which shouldn't be replaced at all, it ends up as 19.900.

```
Dim find1 As Variant
Dim rplc1 As Variant

'Captures the wrong prices and their replacements and executes the correction on the new file
fnd1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheets").Range("D3")
rplc1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheets").Range("D4")

With WS
    .Range("AT2:DW1000").Replace what:=fnd1, Replacement:=rplc1, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
End With
```

So, how can I limit the replacement to exactly what's being searched?

Thanks!

Comment: `LookAt:=xlPart`... that seems like it's the issue.

Comment: `LookAt:=xlWhole`

Comment: @Antonio, can you run find and replace without a macro and see if it works. Just use the XL GUI. Once you have a search term that you like then record a macro that does that. Perhaps you need to search for " 9.9000" with a leading space? It depends on how your data is stored.

Comment: hi @cameront, thanks for your input. It actually had to do with the xlPart VS xlWhole. I had even opened a new tab to read about it, but left the computer and didn't see what it's about.

Comment: @ScottCraner how to mark yours as the answer? Thanks!